# Unexpected distingration energy value during alpha decay equation

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, mass-energy

I am trying to solve the disintgration value of the below decay equation but the issue I am having is my result seems way to high compared to what is expected (around 5-6 MeV).

$$^{213}At  \rightarrow \vphantom{Bi}^{209}Bi + \vphantom{\alpha}^4\alpha + Q$$

My Math as follows:

$$Q = (m_{At} - (m_{Bi} + m_{α} )) * C^2$$

$$Q = (212.992937 - (4.001506179127 + 208.9803987)) * 2997924582$$

$$Q = 9.914739 * 10^{14}$$

to get in MeV:

$$Q = ((212.992936514 - (4.001506179127 + 208.9803987)) * 2997924582) * (1.66054 * 10^{-27}) * (6.242 * 10^{12})$$

$$Q = 10.2767168514 MeV$$

This value of 10 seems to be double what I am expecting and I do not know why.

I would also note I just made this equation myself rather than from any textbook just for my own understanding but I believe the decay parent and children are accurate based on research.

Inputting other mass values such as Thorium and Uranium work to get around 5 MeV so I know my method is correct but I feel like I am missing something theoretical or in my calculation, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: ENSDF gives 9.254 MeV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you expect around 5 MeV?  My 16th edition of the Chart of the Nuclides lists 9.08 MeV as the decay energy
2. I believe that there is a **slight** math error (about 1MeV)

The actual reaction starts with 85 orbital electrons on the astatine atom.

The actual products have the same 85 electrons on the actual daughter isotope Bismuth atom and **none** in the alpha-particle.

***BUT..***

The tabulated mass for the astatine atoms is for the neutral atom, including the **85** orbital atoms. So far, so good.

The tabulated value for the bismuth isotope is again for the neutral $83$ electron atom.  To get figures for the actual daughter isotope mass, you would need to include two more electron masses.

If you use the mass of a neutral helium-4 atom instead of the mass of a helim-4 nucleus, everything would take care of itself.

Look at it this way: The daughter isotope keeps 83 of its electrons, and dumps two on the alpha particle, so you should use the the tabulated values for the isotopes, and the He-4 mass for the alpha particle.

EDIT:
Apply the electron count correction to your calculation and you should hit the value of @jon custer exactly...

Comment: This answer is correct. Q-values are from neutral ground state to neutral ground state (unless specified otherwise). The masses here are for neutral astatine-213 and bismuth-209, but for a bare helium nucleus. A neutral helium atom has mass 4.00260 u, larger than the mass in the question by 0.0011 u ≈ 1 MeV.